# Running profiler causes Julia kernel to die

Tags: julia

When I run the simple profiling [test case](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/profile/) given in the Julia docs, my Julia kernel invariably dies regardless of environment. I've tried julia.exe, JuliaStudio, and Sublime Text with IJulia. I'm running a fresh install (via the standard 64-bit Windows installer) of version 0.3.0 on Windows 8.

Other components of Julia appear to be working without a hitch. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7983) in Julia 0.3.0, and will be fixed in the upcoming Julia 0.3.1

Comment: I updated to the latest build (0.4.0-dev+371) and can verify that the bug is fixed.